# Is it possible to obfuscate or eliminate Http 403 status code

Tags: apache, drupal, http-status-code-403, httpd.conf

A web developer reached out to me to inquire if I could prevent the 403 Forbidden status from showing on a Drupal site. Of course I thought they just wanted a redirect to a 404 page or to the home page but that wasn't it. They wanted to know if I code make the 403 status code something else or prevent it from being sent to the browser.

Example: When someone browses to mysite.com/contact, they are sent to mysite.com/homepage by default because of redirection as I changed the how ErrorDocument handles 403 and 404 errors in Apache. However if you open devtools in any browser you can see that a 403 error is thrown.

The developer would like for that indication of the error code to be removed or replaced by something else. I am pretty sure it isn't possible but I have been wrong in the past so asking. I have done some Googling and can't find anything to put me on the path to finding where that is generated server-side to see if I can manipulate it. Any help would be appreciated as to find out if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, it is not possible to "override" 403 and 404 at server-side level.
What it is possible is to override 403 and 404 error pages through twig template, but it is only a frontend option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).